# Stuck on login screen after update from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: updates, keyboard, 17.10, mouse

I was prompted to update from 16.04 to 17.10. Everything seemed to go well during the update process. After it was done and rebooted, I am stuck on the login screen because neither my keyboard or mouse are working. This happens with my wireless Logitech stuff and with wired USB. I booted into a live version of the latest UbuntuStudio and everything worked as it should.

Maybe the login screen is actually frozen, and it's not a keyboard/mouse issue?? Don't know how I would tell the difference...

Comment: Are you sure you were prompted to update from 16.04 LTS to 17.10 (a EOL release)???  This doesn't smell right to me so I'd suggest you tell us more as to how it happened.  16.04 LTS will offer to upgrade to 18.04 LTS when 18.04.1 is released (in a couple of days; hasn't occurred yet), so if you were offered something, you've probably hacked your system....

Comment: It asked me to update from the same screen I would typically see security and system updates.

Comment: I would suggest trying to switch to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 or another fn key) and try logging in there (it'll fail if machine is completely locked up). Next I'd suggest trying to remote login (via `ssh`) but this assumes you have `openssh-server` installed & running..  The upgrade path you've mentioned can't happen unless the system is corrupt or changed badly (as LTS upgrades only to LTS unless forced out of that path; but won't jump to an EOL release ever), so I'd assume you're system is corrupted and consider re-installing.  Use your 'live' version to backup your data first!!